# Haskell Interactive Mode Setup - cabal unrecognised command: repl

Tags: repl, haskell-mode

I'm trying to set up haskell-mode following this instructions

[0] https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Haskell-Interactive-Mode-Setup

[1] http://tim.dysinger.net/posts/2014-02-18-haskell-with-emacs.html

but when I try to bring the REPL in a .hs file I'm getting the following error:

```
Starting inferior `cabal repl' process using cabal ...
-> :set prompt "\4"
-> Prelude.putStrLn ""
-> :set -v1
<- cabal: unrecognised command: repl (try --help)

Event: "exited abnormally with code 1
"
```

I have the "cabal repl" working.

Do you know what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Edit:

I followed these steps [1]:

```
$ cabal --v
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library 

$ cabal install happy alex
$ cabal install ghc-mod structured-haskell-mode stylish-haskell

$ mkdir haskell-hello
$ cd haskell-hello
$ cabal init
$ touch LICENSE
$ cabal sandbox init

$ perl -p -i -e 's/^.*main-is.*$/  main-is: Main.hs/' haskell-hello.cabal
$ echo 'main = putStrLn "hello world"' > Main.hs
$ cabal install
$ ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/haskell-hello
  hello world
```

Then I open the Main.hs in Emacs. In haskell-mode I try to open a REPL with `haskell-process-load-or-reload` or `haskell-interactive-bring` but this error appears:

```
<- cabal: unrecognised command: repl (try --help)
```

I have `cabal repl` working:

```
$ cabal repl
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude>
```

Edit 2:

When I eval

```
(process-lines "cabal repl")
```

I have the following result

```
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, cabal repl
```

Edit 3:

My haskell configuration on .emacs:

```
;; haskell
(require-package 'haskell-mode)

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)

(eval-after-load "haskell-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-,") 'haskell-move-nested-left)
     (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'haskell-move-nested-right)))

(define-key haskell-mode-map [f7] 'haskell-navigate-imports)

(custom-set-variables '(haskell-stylish-on-save t))

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)

(custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl))

(setq haskell-ghci-program-name "cabal")
(setq haskell-ghci-program-args '("repl"))

(custom-set-variables
  '(haskell-process-suggest-remove-import-lines t)
  '(haskell-process-auto-import-loaded-modules t)
  '(haskell-process-log t))

(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-g") 'haskell-interactive-bring)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'haskell-process-load-or-reload)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t") 'haskell-process-do-type)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-i") 'haskell-process-do-info)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'haskell-process-cabal-build)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'haskell-interactive-mode-clear)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'haskell-process-cabal)
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "SPC") 'haskell-mode-contextual-space)
```

Comment: what exactly have you been doing before this error?  What is your Haskell-related configuration up to this point?  What does "bring the REPL in a .hs file" mean?

Comment: Hi @rekado     
I have added the information you asked. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas Would you mind to add the output of `M-: (process-lines "cabal repl")`?  Probably your Emacs uses another, outdated `cabal`…

Comment: @lunaryorn      I have added the eval output. Do I need to install something especially for emacs? I have only installed `haskell-mode` on emacs and the rest of the packages with `cabal`. I have added also my haskell configuration.

Comment: @Nicolas: please show the output of `(process-lines "cabal" "--v")`.  This should give you the version of the cabal binary Emacs uses. This should include the string `1.20.0.3`.

Comment: @Nicolas Have you solved this yet?  Is there a problem with the answer I provided?

Answer (score 4):

On my system (Fedora 20) the default cabal version that comes with the `haskell-platform` package is `1.16.0.2`.  After installing the latest `cabal-install` (`cabal install cabal-install`), I have a new cabal binary in `~/.cabal/bin/cabal`.

If I don't do any particular configuration in Emacs, `haskell-interactive-bring` will fail with the same error you report.  When I correct the path to the cabal binary, though, everything works just fine:

```
(setq haskell-process-path-cabal "~/.cabal/bin/cabal")
```

Make sure that Emacs uses the correct cabal executable.  If it does not, try setting `haskell-process-path-cabal`.

Comment: this answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: `exec-path-from-shell` is a package that helps you set the path of your Emacs shell to your user path.